# How to bind the 'mouseover' event in a leaflet-routing route?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, routing, event-listener

I'm trying to mimic the GoogleMaps behavior of creating a small white circular marker on a route when you hover on the route.

My idea is to listen for the 'mouseover' event (if there is any) and then create a marker above on the route, but I can't get the object the actually have the 'mouseover' event.

Can it be done?
There's a better solution?

**Edit:**
Found the _line object:

```
routing_control = new L.Routing.control({etc...});
routing_control._line;
```

and this _line contains all the layers that form the polyline so I can do this:

```
var little_ball_marker = new L.Marker(L.latLng(0, 0);
little_ball_marker.setOpacity(0);

routing_control._line.eachLayer(function(pLayer) {
    pLayer.on('mouseover', function(pMouseEvent) {
        little_ball_marker.setOpacity(1);
        little_ball_marker.setLatLng(pMouseEvent.latlng);
    });
}
```

Cool, put it on the routing_control 'routesfound' event and boom, works.

But now when I drag the route or even zoom the map, it stops working, I presume it recreates the lines and since it doesn't trigger the 'routesfound' event I can't get to the layer.

the map object:

```
map = L.map('map-canvas').setView([-27, -52], 4);
```

have the 'layeradd' event, and it keeps firing like crazy, so I presume I can get the recently added layer, but I can't distinguish if the layer currently being added belongs to the route.
Something like:

```
function layer_belongs_to_route(pLayer) {
    return // insert code here...
}

map.on('layeradd', function(pEvent) {
    if layer_belongs_to_route(pEvent.layer) {
        // do the thing
    }
});
```